# Unknown CMake command "add_action_files"

Tags: ros, catkin-make, cmake, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo.

I've been following along with the tutorial at:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv and when I get to the portion where it instructs me to run catkin_make install I get:

```
Base path: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:61 (add_action_files):
  Unknown CMake command "add_action_files".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/umdearborn/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I'm fairly new to ROS and CMake so I'm completely stumped.  I've made sure to source both /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash and ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240228/unknown-cmake-command-%22add_action_files%22/) by [Distractal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27583/distractal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have `add_action_files` on line 61 of your CMakeLists.txt, and cmake doesn't understand that command.

I don't see any mention of it in the tutorial, so you should probably comment out that command.

(for background, the `add_action_files` command is part of [actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) and is used for generating action interfaces, which are a more advanced topic)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Distractal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27583/distractal/) on 2016-07-23**:
You were correct, I mistakenly placed the AddTwoInts.srv line under the add_action_files directive instead of the add_service_files directive.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If someone is facing a similar error check your find_package if actionlib_msgs are added, and also in generate_messages part, that solved this error for

---

Originally posted by [Siddarth09](https://answers.ros.org/users/78598/siddarth09/) with karma: 11 on 2021-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1